# What is the meaning of the word "antiquarian" in this context?

Tags: semantics, meaning

"Although some Humanists were clubbish snobs-an intellectual elite with narrow, **antiquarian** interests-others preached a civic Humanism..."

Comment: This should be asked on English Language & Usage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the present context **antiquarian** seems to refer to the fact that these intellectuals were interested in some humanistic subject merely as a matter of amusement or curiosity, instead of trying to understand it in a more analytical manner.

Comment: I see people keep downvoting my answer. Could they please expand their criticism?